# add a hashtag before input value

Tags: javascript

I had this as part of an input tag:

```
onkeyup = "this.value = '#' + this.value;"
```

Which adds a hashtag with each letter. I only want 1 hashtag.

I also tried this:

```
onkeyup = "if (this.charAt(0) != '#') this.value = '#' + this.value;"
```

and this:

```
onkeyup = "if (this.charAt(0) != '#') this.value = '#' + this.value; return this.value"
```

I know ideally you want to put your scripts in a separate .js file, but this is just a really small project and I wanted to just throw it into the html code.

Comment: The issue with replacing as they type is it can move the cursor. Might be better onblur/change to set it.

Comment: @epascarello That worked perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example

```html
<input onkeyup="if (this.value[0] !== '#') this.value = '#' + this.value"></input>
```

The problem was that you needed to do `this.value.charAt(0)` or `this.value[0]` not `this.charAt(0)`

Hopefully, this helps.

EDIT: As [@epascarello](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14104/epascarello) [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62474338/add-a-hashtag-before-input-value/62474464#comment110487209_62474338) you could also use the `onchange` event instead so that it does not move your cursor as you type.

```html
<input onchange="if (this.value[0] !== '#') this.value = '#' + this.value"></input>
```

Comment: This works perfect. I'm still new to JS but it's good to know my thought process was in the right place. Just missed the `this.value.charAt`. @epascarello made a great suggestion and said just change it to "onchange" which also worked!!

Answer (score 0):

Just get the final value and add it to before the first letter!
something like:

```
let finalword = "#" + this.value.toString.trim();
```

What do you actually need to do with that?

Comment: Thank you for the response. I don't understand enough JS to make this work. but I do appreciate the feedback. Someone else posted a suggestion that I could work with. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would just see if the string includes a `#` and if not, use a ternary operator to concatenate like below:

```
return this.value.includes('#') ? true : '#' + value
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm not really that good at JS, but I've heard of ternary operators. I couldn't get the above to work, but I appreciate the feedback! :)

Comment: Thanks a ton!  Sorry my solution didn't work!  I should have tested it :D

Comment: Based on my limited understanding, it seems to me like your code is saying "check if it has a #, if true, then value = # + value"  but again, I'm really not sure how to read it. I'm in school now, but we haven't gotten to the JS portion just yet!

Comment: That is exactly what it is saying.  If the string ````includes```` a ````#```` then leave it alone but if it does not, add it to the string.  The only problem with this is it doesn't have a good handling for any value that may already have a ````#```` but if the values will be scrubbed of any ````#````, you should be fine.